# rxJava multible group by variables

Tags: java, android, lambda, android-library, rx-java

The example is C# code. I am using RxJava to use lambda in Android.

```
 var dex = device.OrderBy(x => x.Connection1).ThenBy(x => x.EventName1).GroupBy(x => new { x.Connection1, x.EventName1 }, y => new { EventNames = y.EventName1 }).
                Select(x => new { Connector = x.Key.Connection1, EventName = x.Key.EventName1, Counter = x.Select(y => y.EventNames).Count() });
```

So i need this code written in Java with the help of RxJava does anyone know how to use a multible group by in RxJava ???

Comment: You'll need a tuple or pair as a group key.

Comment: can you post an answer with the solution code and mark it as answered?